# How do filter out escape sequences while scraping tables using css selectors?

Tags: html-table, scrapy, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape a table using CSS Selectors in Scrapy. The method I used is scraping row by row into a single scrapy.Field() in an item object.

However, the data scraped contains a "\n\t\t" element between every other element in the table. How do I remove this in the scraping process. I can do post-processing on the data but I would like to understand what is going on.

My parse method:

```
 def parse_product(self, response):

    l = ItemLoader(item = KdramaItem(),
                   response = response,
                   )
    l.add_value('url', response.meta['source_url'])
    table_loader = l.nested_css('table')
    table_loader.add_css('table', 'tr ::text')

    yield l.load_item()
```

Part of output:

```
"url": ["http://www.koreandrama.org/angels-last-mission-love/"], "table": ["\n\t\t", "Date", "\n\t\t", "Ep", "\n\t\t", "TNmS", "\n\t\t", "TNmS", "\n\t\t", "AGB", "\n\t\t", "AGB", "\n\t", "\n\t\t", "\u00a0", "\n\t\t", "\u00a0", "\n\t\t", "Nationwide", "\n\t\t", "Seoul", "\n\t\t", "Nationwide", "\n\t\t", "Seoul", "\n\t", "\n\t\t",
```

Comment: Ehm, `\n\t\t` is not an element, it's just harmless white space.

Comment: @MrLister I meant it as an element in the table list